# What is the probability a random integer $x$ when divided by $3$ has a remainder smaller than when $x$ is divided by $9$? without monte-carlo.

Tags: probability, modular-arithmetic, integers, probability-limit-theorems, euclidean-algorithm

[image]

[image]

I noticed the quantity of numbers from 1-100 with remainder zero modulo nine = quantity of numbers from 1-100 with remainder one modulo nine > quantity of numbers from 1-100 with remainder 2 modulo nine=...= the quantity of numbers of remainder eight modulo nine.

You can generalize this two the remainders modulo three.

I came up with 67/101 including zero up to 100. If I omit zero, do I need to omit something else or should I remove zero? That's why monte-carlo on spreadsheets is confusing me.

but how do you calculate this exactly? Does using given probability help? I'm guessing 2/3 is the probability.

I realize the remainder modulo n form a equivalence class, but the remainder 1 modulo 9 is not comparable with the remainder 1 modulo 3.

Comment: Just do it.  The possible remainders when divide by $9$ are $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ and they are all equally likely.  For those the probabilities of those when divided by $3$ are respectively $0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2$ If the remainder is $0,1,2$ the are the same.  If they are $\ge 3$ then the $9$ remainder is long.  So $\frac 69=\frac 23$

Comment: "but the remainder 1 modulo 9 is not comparable with the remainder 1 modulo 3."  Depends on what you are comparing about them.  As $3\mid 9$ and $9 = 3\times 3$ then $x\equiv 1 \pmod 3 \iff x\equiv 1+3k \pmod 9$ where $k = 0, 1,2$.  $1+3k > 1$ iff $k > 0$ and the probability of $k>0$ is $\frac 23$.... Another way to do this is to consider than for any number $n$ that $n=9m + R$ for some $m$ and some $R=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$.  Now $R= 3k + r$ where $k=0,1,2$ and $r=0,1,2$  Now $R > r \iff k> 0$. There are $3$ values of $k$ and $2$ are more than $0$.  So prob is $\frac 23$.

Comment: A harder question is remainder mod $m,n$ where $m < n$ but none else is none.  But that's doable.

Comment: What does "a random integer" mean? What probability distribution are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each remainder $\pmod 9$ is equally probable, and the ones that have the property you seek are $\{3,4,5,6,7,8\}\pmod 9$.  Hence the answer is $\frac 69=\frac 23$, in line with your simulation and conjecture.

A note on the probability:  I am speaking of the limit, of course.  For any particular cutoff $N$ there may be some slight bias.  Indeed, fix the cutoff $N$ and let $r_N$ be the remainder of $N$ divided by $9$ Then the number of natural numbers $≤N$ with remainder $r$ is given by $$  
\begin{cases}
\big \lfloor \frac N9\big \rfloor,  & \text{if $r>r_N$ } \\ \\
\big \lfloor \frac N9\big \rfloor+1, & \text{if $1≤r≤r_N$}\\ \\\big \lfloor \frac N9\big \rfloor,  & \text{if $r=0$ } 
\end{cases}\\$$

If $N$ is large, the additive factor of $1$ has no significant impact on the probability.  Of course, if $N$ is small it does matter.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151359/discussion-on-answer-by-lulu-what-is-the-probability-a-random-integer-x-when-d); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.